# Open + Edit Excel file from Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open an excel file from a sharepoint library bearing the same name via VBA. Here are variables

Define Variables:

```
Private Master_File As String
Private Master_FileLocation As String
Private Master_Open As Workbook
```

Assign_Variables:

```
Master_File = "Master Data.xlsx"
Master_FileLocation = "http://sharepoint/page"


Sub Open_Master()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Master_Open = Workbooks.Open(Master_File)

    If Master_Open Is Nothing Then

         Workbooks.Open FileName:=Master_FileLocation & "/" & Master_File, ReadOnly:=False

    End If

  End Sub
```

The code runs with no errors yet no excel file is opened. When I click on the file and copy the "shortcut" directly from my internet explorer browser, this is what appears:

```
   http://sharepoint/org/%20Master%20Data/%20Master%20Data.xlsx
```

When I copy this path and paste it into a folder search bar I am able to open the folder. Therefore, I know the file + folder exists. I also understand some functions such as ChDir and GetOpenFileName don't work with HTTP. That said, my function is pretty simple and doesn't require those functions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "The code runs with no errors"  - you told it to ignore any errors.  What happens if you comment out the `On Error Resume Next`?  The "working" link is pretty different from the one in your code (even ignoring the space >> %20 differences) - do you really have leading spaces as shown?

Comment: Also - your post title has "Open + Edit" - you cannot edit and save [back to the original location] if you open the file via HTTP